# write or update a special row in SQL table - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I design a company profile form in Visual studio 2019 and I save data in a table in SQL, I want to save information just in one row because it is my customer info and it is unique
I can not write and update this row
first of all I select Whole data from table to check is it null or not?
then if it is null it means this is first time => I insert data
else => user wants to update => I Update data

this is my code:

```cs
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CompanyProfile where id=@N", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", "1");
    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr["CompanyName"].ToString() == null)
        {
            con.Close();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CompanyProfile(ComanyName,RegNo,RegDate,NID,EID,WorkShopCode,WebSite,CEOName,Tel,Mobile,Fax,ZipCode,Email,Address,Logo)values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n,@o)", con);
            if (PBLogo.Image == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please insert PIC");
                return;
            }
            if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
            byte[] ar = File.ReadAllBytes(PBLogo.ImageLocation);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtCompanyName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", txtRegNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", txtRegDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", txtNID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", txtEID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtWorkShopCode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", txtWebSite.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", txtCEOName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", txtTel.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", txtMobile.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", txtFax.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", txtZipCode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@o", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = ar;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("form saved");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                byte[] arrPic = ms1.GetBuffer();
                ms1.Close();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                string Updatetable = "Update CompanyProfile set CompanyName='" + txtCompanyName.Text + "',RegNo='" + txtRegNo.Text + "',RegDate='" + txtCompanyName.Text + "',NID='" + txtNID.Text + "',EID='" + txtEID.Text + "',WorkShopCode='" + txtWorkShopCode.Text + "',Website='" + txtWebSite.Text + "',CEOName='" + txtCEOName.Text + "',Tel='" + txtTel.Text + "',Mobile='" + txtMobile.Text + "',Fax='" + txtFax.Text + "',ZipCode='" + txtZipCode.Text + "',Email='" + txtEmail.Text + "',Address='" + txtAddress.Text + "',Pic=@Pic where id=@Y";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Y", "1");
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Updatetable, con);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic", arrPic);
                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("form updated");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this error occurred : `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'CompanyName'`

1. what is the problem and how can I fix it?
2. is this a suitable method to write or update just one row?

Comment: Why are you doing all that concatenation when you clearly know how to use parameters? Do it properly.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown exactly? Please provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: You could save a lot of ceremony by using a MERGE statement to "upsert" into the table. And, what line do you get the error on?

Comment: What use is that `MemoryStream` when you never write any data to it?

Comment: @ jmcilhinney : Exception Unhandled ->   if (dr["CompanyName"].ToString() == null)

Comment: That would suggest "CompanyName" is not a column of "CompanyProfile". Using `SELECT *` is not a good choice for various reasons. In this case you would get an error sooner and it would be more descriptive.

Comment: Possible spelling error `CompanyName` (in the SELECT and UPDATE statements) vs. `ComanyName` (in the INSERT)

Comment: Just use `ORM` and save your time and effort.

Comment: Do your server have more than one database?  You would get your error if you where writing to the wrong database.  Use SQL Server management studio and connect to the database shown in your connection string.  Then check under Database tab the databases in the server.  You can also verify the columns in the database to make sure there is a column ComanyName